# Django SearchFilter exists relationship without DISTINCT

Tags: django, optimization, search, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Table search is implemented through **rest_framework.filters SearchFilter** with the addition of DISTINCT, which is not suitable for a large database, how to avoid this, what are the hacks for this

```
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.order_by('-created')

    filter_backends=(
        SearchFilter,
        DjangoFilterBackend,
    )
    search_fields = (
        'id',
        'email',
        'comments__id',
    )
```

thought about adding   `annotate(cnt=Count('comments',filter=Q(comments__id__icontains=search)).filter(cnt)` to get_queryset, but then it's not clear when to do 'OR'